# How do I make git ignore the .git folders under vendor/?

Tags: git, composer-php, gitignore

I am using composer, and for development I want to keep the .git folders in the vendor directory, so I can track diffs, etc.  So my project structure is:

```
projectroot/
  .gitignore
  file1
  file2
  vendor/
    dir1/
      module1/
        .git/
        module1file1
        module1file2
        ...
    dir2/
      module2/
        .git/
        module2file1
        ...
```

I would like to commit to git, these files:

```
file1
file2
vendor/dir1/module1/module1file1        
vendor/dir1/module1/module1file2    
vendor/dir2/module2/module2file1        
...
```

What should my projectroot/.gitignore file be?  From [the composer docs](https://getcomposer.org/doc/faqs/should-i-commit-the-dependencies-in-my-vendor-directory.md) I tried

```
vendor/*.git
```

and

```
vendor/*/.git
```

but in both cases, git 1.8.3 still wants to commit `vendor/dir1/module1` and `vendor/dir2/module2` as submodules, where I want to commit the files underneath instead.

What should the .gitignore syntax be in that case?

Comment: Try `vendor/**/.git`?

Answer (score 1):

I put `vendor/` into the .gitignore file - among others - then, if I want to edit a library I've brought in with Composer (unless it pulled in a 'dist' archive file version), I can do so, and it will still have the libraries .git directory. As the library is its own repo, I can edit and push as I need, but it still is usable from the top-level application (or library).

Comment: I was hoping to commit the vendor files (e.g., `vendor/dir1/module1/module1file1`) directly to the master repo so I can see at a glance what was changed via `git diff`.  Due to the fact that the vendor repos are several layers under `/vendor` I cannot see changes by looking at `/vendor` and would need to recurse manually into each repo and check those one by one.  But maybe that's what people typically do with composer?